# How does GDI+ work with the byte array of images?

Tags: c#, drawing, gdi+

I want to get a better understanding of what happens when I tell a graphics object to draw something. More specifically how does GDI+ set the pixels' colors of the image.

I searched for the source code, but apparently it is not released yet (I found out that a .dll handles the actual drawing, after searching for an answer in here: https://referencesource.microsoft.com).

The whole point of this is for me to be able to define my own way to change the colors of pixels when drawing.

I am not sure if I am on the right track with this code:

```
 public unsafe Bitmap enlargeImg(Bitmap source, int newWidth, int newHeight)
    {
        int resMod = (int)Math.Min(newWidth / source.Width, newHeight / source.Height);
        Bitmap res = new Bitmap(source.Width * resMod, source.Height * resMod, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
        Graphics larGfx = Graphics.FromImage(res);
        SolidBrush br;
        int pxsz = 4;//for 32 bits per pixel
        System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData btd = source.LockBits(
            new Rectangle(0, 0, source.Width, source.Height),
            System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, source.PixelFormat);
        for (int r = 0; r < source.Height; r++)
        {
            byte* bfrw = (byte*)btd.Scan0 + r * btd.Stride;
            for (int c = 0; c < source.Width; c++)
            {
                byte B = bfrw[c * pxsz + 0];
                byte G = bfrw[c * pxsz + 1];
                byte R = bfrw[c * pxsz + 2];
                byte A = bfrw[c * pxsz + 3];
                br = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(A, R, G, B));
                larGfx.FillRectangle(br, c * resMod, r * resMod, resMod, resMod);
            }
        }
        source.UnlockBits(btd);
        return res;
    }
```

Here I try to scan through an image and draw a new image, where each pixel is made larger. However, this is a lot slower than simply resizing the image with `Graphics.DrawImage` . Yes, I did try `SetPixel` but it is a light year slower.

Note, that I am doing all this for a 2D game engine (thus I have a game cycle), so things must be as fast as possible.

So, how does GDI+ work with the byte arrays of images?

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/LuizZak/FastBitmap

Comment: If it needs to be as fast as possible GDI/.net is perhaps the worst possible combination.

Comment: @Aron I dunno, I can think of a lot of worse ways.

Answer (score 0):

The following method will be a lot faster:

- first change the colors on a bitmap of equal size of the original (so that you only have to change one pixel for each color) - or change the colors of the original if that is allowed. To change the colors, work directly on the buffer of the second (or original) bitmap (just as you are doing now to read the bytes in the original bitmap) - i.e. write those `B G R A bytes` directly to the image buffer.
- then use [StretchBlt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145120.aspx) to copy the bitmap with the updated colors to a bigger one. This will make the pixels bigger.

This way you also avoid the expensive `new SolidBrush()` in the inner loop.

Also, in order to just change the colors of the bitmap, you can use a single loop over all the pixels (i.e. treat the bitmap as one big 1D array). This way you can also eliminate the multiplications inside the inner loop (just loop through the bytes from beginning to end).